# How get a value with vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new with excel and I have some question.
I was trying to do a search in a range with `Vlookup()`.

I have tried below formula.

```
=vlookup(A1;G1:O1;G3:P3;0)
```

***Please Look the picture:***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would want `HLOOKUP` in this case. Something like `=HLOOKUP(A1;G1:O1;3;0)` (assuming the semi-colon is your separator). Another option is `INDEX` and `MATCH`.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. If you found it fully answered your question, feel free to accept it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX/MATCH` one of good option. Try-

```
=INDEX(G3:P3,,MATCH(C2,G1:P1,0))
```

If you have `EXCEL-365` then `XLOOKUP()` would be best. Try-

```
=XLOOKUP(C2,G1:P1,G3:P3)
```

Also `FILTER()` can play role like-

```
=FILTER(G3:P3,G1:P1=C2)
```